# R Shiny apps - What are the possibilities

Tags: r, shiny

this is a question that is very open-ended, and I am hoping for some advice/discussion. I am very new to Shiny apps in R and their capabilities. I was just wondering if the following would be possible, and how difficult it is to develop.

I have a supervised learning model that classifies geometric parameters (area, circularity, perimeter etc) into different shapes. I have the labeled dataset, with all the training/testing performed already. It then performs statistics and graphs the results. Would it be possible to

1. Have the user import their own data to classify their data into shapes (this user being any random person in the world)
2. Dynamically change the variables that are graphed (e.g. if my data was comparing drug A vs drug B, and a new user was comparing drug C, D, E and F, can they specify what each variable should be called (Drug C D etc), and how many variables are being compared (4)?
3. Do they have to have R installed? If so, would there be lots of input required from the user to use the app?
4. Any other forseeable problems?

Advice is appreciated! This community is really great and I hope someone could guide me on what to begin with and if this project is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your last question first: Yes, this is a feasible project for which a Shiny app can be well suited.

Import your model into the Shiny App Workspace (e.g. with `readRDS()`).

Shiny already comes with many inputs (add more with custom HTML if needed). One input is `fileInput()` which allows users to upload data.

Define a format (.csv/.xlsx/etc..) in which your Shiny app expects the user data. Then make sure that the model can handle the uploaded data (preprocess, filter missing/outlier etc.. if needed).

In which form the result is plotted or basically output, you can also let the user decide (further inputs like `checkboxInput()`, `radioButtons()`, `selectInput()` can be helpful).

And no, the user does not need to have R installed.